# Moving two existing already-synced directory trees to git annex

Tags: git, git-annex

I have two copies of my music files, one on a desktop Linux machine, one on a Macbook.  At the moment, I run rsync periodically to keep these files in sync. I'd like to move management of this problem to `git annex`, but was wondering what the cleanest way to start would be.

In particular, if I independently do

```
git init
git annex init "My music on <Laptop|Desktop>"
```

on both machines, what should I then do to get annex to take over synchronisation  without needing a big synchronisation step subsequently?

Comment: This might be a start: [syncing non-git trees with git-annex
](http://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/syncing_non-git_trees_with_git-annex/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done exactly that a while ago and documented this on the [official tips section of the git-annex website](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/migrating_two_seperate_disconnected_directories_to_git_annex/).

Basically, the answer is that, since git-annex performs decentralised deduplication, there won't be a big sync. So on each machine, you can do:

```
git init
git annex init "My music on <Laptop|Desktop>"
git annex add .
git commit -m "git annex yay"
```

Then on one of the machines (the laptop, i would suggest), add the other (the desktop) as a remote:

```
git remote add desktop desktop.me.example.com:/srv/music
git annex sync desktop
```

The last sync operation only syncs metadata, mind you, that is the [location tracking](https://git-annex.branchable.com/location_tracking/) data, basically. To copy files around, you will actually want `git annex copy` or `.. move`. Using those techniques, I have been able to keep a smaller subset of my music collection on my laptop fairly reliably, and even manage it (e.g. rename files, import new files) while being offline while never worry about losing files.